# Linux tool for http downloading using multiple connections via multiple interfaces

Tags: linux, utilities, download

Is there a tool that allows http file download using multiple network interfaces and multiple connections? I'd like to test my overall internet connection speed by downloading a large file via multiple interfaces. Something like lftp with wget —bind-address option

Comment: Note that you can't download a single file (or web page) on multiple interfaces (unless the server you are contacting uses a multi-homing protocol like SCTP, but that's unlikely). You can download *several* files at the same time on different interfaces via different HTTP connections, though.

Comment: Why did you decide so? My client has multiple interfaces, what could prevent it to create several sockets bound to different addresses, connect them to the server and download different ‘range’ of file? Please explain

Comment: Because standard TCP and UDP protocols are *single homed*. Every connection must go through a specific interface, because you can only have a single IP address at each end. That's how the protocol works. So multiple interfaces won't make "your internet faster" (though many people wish this, this is a FAQ). The best you can do is to more or less randomly distribute connections among your interfaces. Or do a failover.

Comment: Of course you can write an application to download different parts of some file via HTTP on several connections, if the server supports it, but you must explicitly do so, and decide on the ranges, and I don't know any application that already does it. You could use bittorrent, which already makes use of many connections, but not HTTP. And bittorrent won't help with measuring speed.

Comment: ‘Every connection goes through a specific interface’ - correct. ‘Use of multiple interfaces won’t make overall speed faster’ - incorrect. Think again )))

Comment: Many apps (like lftp) can download multiple ‘ranges’ simultaneously. It really increases download speed in most cases by different reasons that really doesn’t matter in my case. Although, I cannot find any that allows to use multiple interfaces for that. It’s easy to make such an app, but i supposed there should be some already implemented  this

Comment: As I said: You need to explicitly distribute connections over interfaces. It won't work magically. If you want to play with multi-homing procotols, [multipath TCP](https://www.multipath-tcp.org) has a server you can connect when you manage to get multipath TCP working on your machine.

Comment: Well, didn’t think it’s so hard to imagine. Let me explain it further on example - let’s suppose, there’s a server with one 100mbps connection. A client has 2 connections, 10mbps each. It’s obvious, that every single connection will give the client the most of 10mbps. But two simultaneous connections will give 20, its so obvious, i wonder how couldn’t you understand that )))

Comment: ‘You need to explicitly distribute connections over interfaces’ ,- sure, that’s what I’m looking for ))) and no ‘multipath’ is required - man bind ))))

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use `wget` with the `--bind-address` download option:

> `--bind-address=ADDRESS`
>
> When making client TCP/IP connections, bind to ADDRESS on the local machine.  ADDRESS may be specified as a hostname or IP address.  This option can be useful if your machine is bound to multiple IPs.

Simultaneously run a copy of `wget` on each interface. I am currently unable to test this, but I'm quite certain that the download will come from the interface that `wget` is bound to.

Alternatively, to allow multiple TCP connections on each network interface, you can use `btdownloadcurses` with the `--bind` option:

> `--bind ip`
>
> bind to ip instead of the default

Comment: I know about this option, it works, but wget cannot download in multiple threads. This limits speed. Also, I couldn’t calculate the overall speed, and i need exactly this

Comment: I improved my question with this

Comment: I'm confused. If you run 2 `wget` processes at the same time, they will use different threads. Then, isn't the your overall speed just the sum of the speed of the individual downloads, e.g. 2.4 Mbps on one interface, 1.4 Mbps on another, overall 3.8 Mbps? What am I missing?

Comment: Not really. First, it,s hard to run them really simultaneously to check the overall speed. But it’s not the main issue. Second, single-thread download is usually slower, at least in my case (tried centos “all” image)

Comment: I updated my answer with an option that is multi-threaded per network interface. Perhaps a simple script could be used to run them simultaneously and even add the speeds together.

Comment: But I thought it’s for torrents only, isn’t it?

Comment: Sure, but downloading torrents is a great way to test your download bandwidth. Go to [Ubuntu alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) to get some `.torrent` files for testing where you don't have to question the legality or availability. Ubuntu provides seeding servers to ensure torrent downloads are always fast.

Comment: It’s quite hard to ensure there’s enough peers with enough speed. You’d never know, is it your limit or your peers are limited. that’s why I stated in the question that I require http

Comment: Oh, wait - I think `btdownloadcurses` supports http downloads too, though I can't say if it will download a single URL with multiple threads.

Comment: Tried it with the —url option - nothing

Comment: Try with just the URL, no options.

Comment: Nothing. Don't work

Answer (score 0):

In case of HTTP or HTTPS, as long as server supports range requests you can fetch the ranges separately and stitch them together. I started working on a use case that is pointed by you. If you are still interested, here is a link to my repository https://github.com/m0hithreddy/MID.

- The program (MID) uses SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option to bind to a specific interface, so in most of the cases you require super user permissions and CAP_NET_RAW capability (root user has).
- MID determines the network interfaces to be used in the download and adopts two step split for downloading the content.

  - First step: The file is divided among network interfaces (in real time).
  - Second step: Further the file is divided among several **HTTP range requests** that arises from that particular interface (**NOTE**: Server should support them at the first place to make all of this possible)

Your use case ends here... But some more features of MID are... Support for HTTPS protocol, GZIP encodings (if server supports them).

If you are keen about using MID for HTTP only run `./configure` with `--without-ssl` argument (`./configure --without-ssl`)

Cheers :)